# Unexpected results with Integrate/AsymptoticIntegrate with assumptions

Tags: numerical-integration, assumptions, asymptotics

I am quite disturbed by the result provided by Mathematica, and I am not sure if I understand perfectly its behavior.

What I want to do is to check the asymptotic form of the function $I(\tau)$ with $\tau \to \infty$ and: $$ I(\tau) = \int_0^\pi \frac{e^{2a(\cos(\theta)-1)\tau} \sin(\theta)^2}{a^2 - 2a\cos(\theta)
+ 1} d \theta $$ where there is a free variable $a > 1$.

Now, if I am not mistaken, this can be solved using first a change of variable, say $u = -2a(\cos(\theta)-1)$, and we get that $du = 2a \sin(\theta) d \theta$ so that: $$ I(\tau) = \int_0^{4a} \frac{e^{-u \tau} (1 - \left(1-\frac{u}{2a}\right)^2)^\frac12 }{a^2 + u - 2a + 1} \frac{d u}{2a} $$ so: $$ I(\tau) = \int_0^{4a} \frac{e^{-u \tau} (\frac{u}{2a} (2 + \frac{u}{2a}) )^\frac12 }{u + (a-1)^2} \frac{d u}{2a} $$

Now, we can use [watson lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Watson%27s_lemma) and get the nice result: $$ I(\tau) \sim \frac{\Gamma(\frac32)}{2a \sqrt{a} (a-1)^2 \tau^\frac32 } $$

Now for example, with $a=2$ we get $I(\tau) \sim \frac{\sqrt{\pi}}{8 \sqrt{2} \tau^\frac32}$

and this is exactly what I get if I type for $a=2$:

```
AsymptoticIntegrate[
 E^(2*2*(Cos[\[Theta]] - 1)*\[Tau])*
  Sin[\[Theta]]^2/(4 + 1 - 2*2*Cos[\[Theta]]), {\[Theta], 
  0, \[Pi]}, \[Tau] -> \[Infinity]]
```

However, when I type the "general form"

```
AsymptoticIntegrate[
 E^(2*a*(Cos[\[Theta]] - 1)*\[Tau])*
  Sin[\[Theta]]^2/(a^2 + 1 - 2*a*Cos[\[Theta]]), {\[Theta], 
  0, \[Pi]}, \[Tau] -> \[Infinity], 
 Assumptions -> a > 1 && a \[Element] Reals]
```

It would return a completely different result (after a loooong calculation (why?)) $$ \frac{\pi  e^{-4 a \tau }}{2 \left(a^2+2 a+1\right)} $$

Being new to using this software, my hypothesis is that Mathematica might apply its assumption only at the end of the computation, and thus is probably doing stuff assuming $a$ is complex or so. To try to test my hypothesis, I have noticed that `Integrate[x^n, x, Assumptions -> n == 2]` returns a correct $\frac{x^3}{3}$ given the assumption, while the following
`Integrate[x^n, x, Assumptions -> n == -1]` returns $\frac{x^{1+n}}{1+n}$ which is wrong given the assumption (should be $\ln(x)$)

Is there any way I could get the expected solution using something different?

Thank you in advance for your help!

Comment: They seem to be bugs. Interestingly no problem with `Assuming[n == -1, Integrate[x^n, x]]`, which trick is usually discouraged. It doesn't help with the `AsymptoticIntegrate` problem though.

Comment: Cannot confirm it: `AsymptoticIntegrate[
 E^(2*a*(Cos[\[Theta]] - 1)*\[Tau])*
  Sin[\[Theta]]^2/(a^2 + 1 - 2*a*Cos[\[Theta]]), {\[Theta], 
  0, \[Pi]}, \[Tau] -> \[Infinity], Assumptions -> a > 1]` returns the input in 12.2.

Comment: @user64494 For what it's worth, here is the result published on wolfram cloud: https://www.wolframcloud.com/obj/5a4c72cf-5f91-4d34-987d-e61552d88a72

Comment: @user2673062: First, the cloud machine works on Linux. Second, the assumption `a \[Element] Reals]` is superfluous since `a>1` implies it.

Comment: @user64494 Hmm, I am not sure I understand about the point that you want to raise, but first this code ran and was published from a macbook (not from the cloud machines). As  for the second point, I appeared to realize that but telling myself more assumptions couldn't hurt. Or am I making wrong assumptions?

Comment: @user2673062: See [that screen](https://www.dropbox.com/s/k5q3zh7o0mj7opn/screen25.01.21.docx?dl=0)

Comment: @user64494 I see, it may also be related to the release version then (as I have 12.1.1.0, and you seem to have 12.2)